# Google Scripts. Как узнать что была произведена новая запись в таблицу?

Tags: javascript, google-spreadsheet, google-apps-script

Нужно для Google таблици создать скрипт, который сработает как только форма создаст новую запись в таблице. Наверняка вопрос простой но я новичок в данной сфере. Заранее всем обратившим внимание спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотрите в сторону триггера Form Submit. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events

Будет скрипт что-то типа такого:

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  // какая -то Ваша логика
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вам такое решение?

```
    var CountVar1 = document.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].childElementCount;
    if ( CountVar1 == x ) {
    console.log( "По прежнему ничего не изменилось.");
    } else {
    console.log( "Добавлена запись" );
    };
```

Comment: ну это нацелено, если известно в какую именно строку должна произвестись запись.